# Sound Synchronization Issues

Tags: signal-processing, labview

We are going to develop a Project on Sound Source Localization using Labview. Still We are on intial stage and going to perform all task on Software base with four mic connected with PC (For initial stage, later on going to develop using NI hardware if possible).

Initially we acquireing sound from 4 Different Microphones connected with computer through USB. Here all microhpones acquiring sound from single sound source with some delay(mili seconds) beacuse of their different position. But this Sound data acquired by USB are not able to write to sound card simulteneously. This data of sound acquire some hold time while writing to the sound card and we are getting some delay samples while synchronizaing these all sounds. Is there any idea to reduce this hold time of sounds that writes the data to the sound card?

Suppose hold time 10ms, want to reduce this to the micro seconds of nano seconds.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'hold time' - are you worried about reducing the delay between the sound reaching the microphone(s) and the data reaching the PC to a minimum, or only about ensuring that the samples from all four microphones are synchronised?

Answer (score 0):

Reducing of the hold time as well as precise inter-channel synchronisation are not possible with LabVIEW running under Windows, and regular sound acquisition hardware. Internal software delays comparable with the time slice are to be expected (~10ms).
You need at least dedicated acquisition hardware (not a number of USB sound cards), and, if you would like to have precise synchronisation of your output with the input with minimum jitter, you need NI-FPGA. Giving these requirements, I would look at the [R-series](http://www.ni.com/rseries/)